# Neat code to convert bool[] -> "false, true, true, false"

Tags: c#, string, arrays

How would you convert an array of booleans to a string like "false, true, true, false" - using as few  lines of code as possible?

Python allows me to use the following (very nice and clean):

```
", ".join(map(str, [False, True, True, False]))
```

In C#, `string.Join` only allows me to join an array of strings.

So what is a short way to do the same in C#?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var array = new[] { true, false, false };
var result = string.Join(", ", array.Select(b => b.ToString()).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
String.Join(", ", new List<Boolean>() { true, false, false, true }.ConvertAll(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Comment: This would throw a `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: You can remove the `()` after `new List<Boolean>` when you specify elements.

Comment: That's fine if he already has a list, but the question specified an array.  To use ConvertAll in that case, you'd first have to construct the list from the array, then do the conversion.  LINQ `Select` works in both cases.

Comment: @tvanfosson...to be fair it is easy enough to convert an array to a list e.g. new List<Boolean>(MyArrayOfBool). However, I do agree the Select on this occassion would be the way to go.

Comment: @James - note, though, that it requires 50% more storage (3 times the original amount at the peak) to create the list, then do the conversion and end up with the converted elements than it does to use `Select`.

Answer (score 4):

```
arrayOfBools.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((x, y) => x + ", " + y)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **.NET 4**, the following line is enough, because [`String.Join<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd992421.aspx) internally calls the `ToString()`-method for every item.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", new[] { false, true, true, false }));

>>>> False, True, True, False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var boolStrings = string.Join(",", new List<bool> { false, true, true, false }
      .ConvertAll(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of

```
var s = from item in blnArray select item.Tostring();
```

Then use the enumerable s to populate the string array?

Not actually tested this - this is just how I might approach it if I were asked to look at it...

Answer (score 1):

```
 var str = string.Join(", ", new List<Boolean>() {false, true, false}.ToArray());
 Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var bools = new bool[] {false, true, true, false};
var strings = bools.Aggregate((x,y) => x.ToString()+","+y.ToString());
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work because the lambda return value must be boolean.